# Complex number (finding range of values)

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> Let $z_1 = 2 e^{i\pi/6}$ and $z_2 = re^{i\theta}$, where $r>0$ and $0\le\theta<2\pi$. Find the range of values of $r$ and $\theta$ for which $z_1z_2$ is:
>
> a) a real number greater than $5$
>
> b) a purely imaginary number with modulus less than $1$

This question was in my math textbook and I can't figure it out. There are no worked example to show the method in the textbook. Any hint on how I should approach it. I converted $z_1$ from polar to rectangular form and got $z_1 = \sqrt 3 + i$

I think $\theta$ has to be greater than $\pi$ and less than $2\pi$ because that will make value of $\sin\theta$ negative which would give the multiplication of $z_1z_2$ the form of $(a+b)(a-b)$ removing the imaginary part and leaving only real number. But I don't know how to get the number to be greater than $5$.

> Answer in the textbook is
>
> a) $r>5/2$ and $\theta=11\pi/6$
>
> b) $r<1/2$ and $r > 0$ and $\theta=\pi/3$ or $\theta=4\pi/3$

Comment: Hint: cis$\theta_1 \times $cis$\theta_2 = $cis$(\theta_1+\theta_2)$.

Comment: What is 'cis' here?

Comment: $cis(\theta)=cos(\theta)+i\cdot sin(\theta)$, where $i^2=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_1=2e^{i\pi/6}$ and $z_2=re^{i\theta}$ where anyways $r\gt0$ and $0\leq\theta\lt2\pi$

Now the product $z_1z_2=2re^{i(\theta+i\pi/6)}$
The argument of the above complex number is $2r$ and for the first part:

$1.)$**$$2r>5$$** which means **$$r>\frac{5}{2}$$**

To make $z_1z_2$ as a real number the argument should be $0$ $or$ $2\pi$ which means
**$$ \theta+\pi/6=2\pi$$** giving **$$\theta=11\pi/6$$**

And for the second Part:

$2.)$ The modulus of $z_1z_2$ is to be less than $1$ so
**$$2r\lt1$$**
Giving **$$r\lt\frac{1}{2}$$** Also the amplitude is a positive quantity, $r\gt0$
Combining you get **$$0\lt r\lt\frac{1}{2}$$**
And to make the number purely imaginary the argument should be either $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$ 
**$$\theta+\pi/6=\pi/2\space or\space 3\pi/2$$**
So the values for $\theta$ will be **$$\theta = \pi/3 \space or \space 4\pi/3$$**
Hope this helps ….